# Sending command to a running cmd process

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have started a command line MP3-player (Fmedia). How do I send (Hotkeys) commands to that app. when it's running? I have the PID.

I can't seem to find it, besides a way to kill a running proccess.

```
Dim strApp, PID
strApp = "C:\Take5-V4\fmedia\fmedia-gui.exe """ & strFilename & """"
PID = Shell(strApp, vbNormalFocus)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SendKeys` to send hotkeys.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement) on it has an example that's nearly exactly what you want. I've adapted it to your needs:

```vb
Dim strApp, PID
strApp = "C:\Take5-V4\fmedia\fmedia-gui.exe """ & strFilename & """"
PID = Shell(strApp, vbNormalFocus)
AppActivate PID
SendKeys "A", True 'Sends the A key to your program.
```

If you don't want to activate the application, it's still possible through the WinAPI SendMessage method, but substantially more complex.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. I know now it was a silly question. It's on some of the first pages of the user manual. I didn't remember it so. But thank you. Stackoverflow is a nice site with nice people.